# Gcc error: cannot specify -c and -o with multiple files

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

I would like to compile many source files assemble them but do not link them
I use a makefile like the following

```
sources = $(wildcard absolut_path_to_source_files/*.c)
objects = absolut_path_to_source_files_folder
compile = $(foreach p,$(sources), gcc -c $(p) -o $(objects)/$(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(notdir $(p)) ))
all:
     $(compile)
```

I get a gcc error that the two flags `-c` and `-o` cannot be used at the same time for several source files,

```
    gcc: fatal error: cannot specify -o with -c, -S or -E with multiple files
    compilation terminated.
```

which is something I don't understand since it is used inside the `foreach` function which calls gcc for one and only one source file at a time (iteration).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a bad idea. Basically you command is invalid, because it is like `gcc -c file1.c -o foo/file1.o gcc -c file2.c -o foo/file2.o` - shell have no means to know when first command ends and second begins. If you really have to, you can add `;` to the tail of each of your generated compile commands, so they at least be separated:

```
compile = $(foreach p,$(sources), gcc -c $(p) -o $(objects)/$(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(notdir $(p)));)
```

However, what you should do is e.g.:

```
BUILDDIR:=build
sources:=$(wildcard *.c)
objects:=$(addprefix $(BUILDDIR)/, $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(sources)))

$(BUILDDIR)/%.o: %.c
    gcc -c $^ -o $@

all: $(objects)
```